# how to implement a single function by passing two string values in ios? may i know how to use secondgpxstring in below program

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

This is my code

```
-(void)gpxFileParsing
{
    NSString *gpxstring = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"gpxtest" ofType:@"gpx"];
    NSString *seconGpxString = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"secondGpxfile" ofType:@"gpx"];
    NSData *gpxdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:gpxstring];
}
```

Comment: what you want to do ?? can you tell me in detail

Comment: your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Below written the method "gpxFileParsing" with two parameter

```
 NSString *firstParam = @"gpxtest"; // first param set in the first path
 NSString *secondParam = @"secondGpxfile";  //second param set in the second path
 NSData *getOutput = [self gpxFileParsing:firstParam seconGpxString:secondParam]; // call method like that and return value is "NSData" so get the data and store it in the "getOutput" variable


-(NSData *)gpxFileParsing:(NSString *)gpxtest seconGpxString:(NSString *) secondGpxfile
{
   NSString *gpxstring = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:gpxtest ofType:@"gpx"];
   NSString *seconGpxString = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:secondGpxfile ofType:@"gpx"];
   NSData *gpxdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:gpxstring];

   return gpxdata;
}
```

if you need "seconGpxString" value just change the method return type  "NSData --> NSString" and return "seconGpxString" value.